# How To get current Click object Value in groupedColumn Chart?

Tags: pykcharts

[image]

I have set "click_enable" : "yes"
in groupedColumnchart config &
handle click even like below. I need X-axis name that is (EAST,NORTH etc..)
based on click.
sample data JSON Like.

```
dataObj.data=  [{
            "x": "NORTH",
            "y": 10,
            "group": "above -10",
            "tooltip": "<table class='PykCharts'><tr><th>North above -10</th></tr><tr><td>-10</td></tr></table>"
        }, {
            "x": "NORTH",
            "y": 12,
            "group": "-10.1 to -13.9",
            "tooltip": "<table class='PykCharts'><tr><th>North -10.1 to -13.9</th></tr><tr><td>-12</td></tr></table>"
        }, {
            "x": "NORTH",
            "y": 16.4,
            "group": "-14 to -19.9",
            "tooltip": "<table class='PykCharts'><tr><th>North -14 to -19.9</th></tr><tr><td>-16.4</td></tr></table>"
        }, {
            "x": "NORTH",
            "y": 25,
            "group": "-20 & below",
            "tooltip": "<table class='PykCharts'><tr><th>North -20 & below</th></tr><tr><td>-25</td></tr></table>"
        }]
    var custom = new PykCharts.multiD.groupedColumn(dataObj);
                    custom.addEvents=function(id){
                        console.log(id);
                        console.log($(this)[0]);;

                    }
```

Comment: What output are you getting for the consoles?

Comment: for  console.log(id); = -20& below ,
 console.log($(this)[0]) : whole object but not the selected point;

Comment: Each of the rect is getting a data-id attribute attached to it. The value of that attribute is passed to the addEvents function as second parameter.
custom.addEvents=function(value, id){ console.log(value, id); }. Try this

Comment: Both have same output -20 & below ,-20 & below

Comment: We have looked into the issue and are currently fixing it according to your requirement. We will send you the updated minified file over the email

Answer (score 0):

I found the alternate way.. You can do Somthing like below

You need to store Group name Like this in tooltip 
For My it's SV.. (Note : you can Even Hide in sapn)

```
"<table class='PykCharts'><tr><th>SV -14 to -19.9</th></tr><tr><td>-14.8</td></tr></table>"
```

add in your JS code

```
  custom.addEvents = function (value) {
          var grouparr;
            d3.selectAll("#" + yourdivID + "_svg rect")
                   .attr("fill-opacity", function (d, i) {
                       if (this.getAttribute('fill-opacity') == 1 && d.name == value) {
                           grouparr = d;
                      }
                 });

            var x = grouparr.tooltip;
            var tooltiptext = $(x).find("th").text();
            var res = tooltiptext.split(" ");
            var hg = $.trim(res[0]);
            console.log("hg your group name=="+hg)
            }
```